# nginx server_name from path

Tags: nginx, configuration

My virtual hosts have the a directory structure as

```
/foo/domain.com/cfg/server.cfg
```

It feels a little repetitive to have the `server_name` repeated inside the server config

```
server {
  server_name domain.com;
```

while it could come from the path the configuration file is in.
Below a pseudo code example just for the explanation:

```
server {
  server_name ${PATH_OF_FILE.split('/')[-2]};
```

Is there a way to refer to that part of the path somehow?
Or is the only alternative to use configuration management?

Comment: for me its unclear what you trying to solve, you did not tell what you tried already

Comment: I've adjusted the question and added some pseudo code/config. I hope that makes it a little clearer. I want to use part of the file path as server_name.